# Deploying a php application in xampp

Tags: php, xampp

I am trying to deploy qdpm_8.2 in xampp in OS Solaris. I am copying the folder of qdpm in htdocs. When I try and open the file index.php in (qdPM_8.2/INSTALL/..) the php code in the file is not running and i am getting just a simple html page

This is the code of my index.php file

`

```
 <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

    include('lib/databaseHelper.php');

    if($_GET['step']=='qdpm_config') include('actions/check_db_settings.php');
    if($_GET['action']=='install_qdpm') include('actions/install_qdpm.php');

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />      
    <meta name="language" content="en" /> 
    <title>qdPM 8.2 Installation</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/main.css" /> 
    </head> 
  <body>      
  <div id="page"> 

    <div id="header-wrap"> 
      <div id="header"> 
        <div id="logo-section">qdPM 8.2 Installation</div>                  
      </div> 
    </div> 

    <div class="shadow-top"><div class="shadow-top-bar"></div></div>  
    <div id="center-wrap">  
      <div id="center"> 
        <div id="content"> 

          <?php if(!$_GET['step']) include('modules/checking_environment.php')?>
          <?php if($_GET['step']=='database_config') include('modules/database_config.php')?>
          <?php if($_GET['step']=='qdpm_config') include('modules/qdpm_config.php')?>
          <?php if($_GET['step']=='success') include('modules/success.php')?>


        </div> 

      </div> 
    </div> 

    <div class="patch_minheight"></div> 
    <div id="footer_guarantor"></div> 
  </div> 



  <div id="footer-wrap"> 
    <div class="shadow-bottom"></div> 
    <div id="footer"> 
      <div class="footer-text">       
        <br>
        qdPM 8.2 | <a class="footer-text" target="_blank" href="http://qdpm.net/free-project-management-forum/index.php">Forum</a> | <a class="footer-text" target="_blank" href="http://qdpm.net/contact_us.php">Contacts</a>      <br>      
       Copyright @ 2010 <a title="Project Management, Time Tracking, Support Tickets" class="footer-text" target="_blank" href="http://qdpm.net/">qdpm.net</a>

      </div> 

    </div> 
  </div> 

  </body> 
</html> `
```

and the errors I am getting are:-

```
[Sat Aug 03 15:36:16 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  include(lib/databaseHelper.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/xampp/htdocs/PMIS/install/index.php on line 4

[Sat Aug 03 15:36:16 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'lib/databaseHelper.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/xampp/lib/php') in /opt/xampp/htdocs/PMIS/install/index.php on line 4

[Sat Aug 03 15:36:16 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  include(modules/checking_environment.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/xampp/htdocs/PMIS/install/index.php on line 33

[Sat Aug 03 15:36:16 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'modules/checking_environment.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/xampp/lib/php') in /opt/xampp/htdocs/PMIS/install/index.php on line 33

[Sat Aug 03 15:36:16 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] script '/opt/xampp/htdocs/PMIS/index.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/PMIS/install/index.php
```

Comment: So what do the servers log files say?

Comment: I think, am not sure qdpm needs to be in domain root. Also you would get a simple html page even if php ran

Comment: How do you open index.php file? You should open it in browser, for example http://localhost/PMIS/install/index.php This is what you did?